# Convert OEM Windows XP box to virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, license, windows-activation, oem

I know I can technically convert an existing Windows XP box to a virtual machine. (e.g. VMWare converter). What I do not quite understand is whether I can then actuall *use* this image/guest.

The current Windows XP box is a years old stock office PC with a Windows XP OEM installation that has assembled it's share of "small business" apps that I shudder to try to reinstall. The current hardware nears it's end of life however, and I'm trying to find a solution that keeps the old installation accessible, preferrable as a simple VM on a shiny new Win764 box. That way, all is on one machine.

However, [as far as my research went so far](https://superuser.com/questions/358138/does-windows-notice-when-a-vm-is-moved-around), it seems Windows (re-)activation will fail for an image of this machine, because it is a OEM Windows XP.

Note: [No answer here](https://superuser.com/q/362044/50211) and [no answer here](https://superuser.com/q/354271/50211) [or here](https://superuser.com/q/73748/50211).

---

I'll add that [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6129573_convert-oem-vlk-xp.html) (from [here](https://superuser.com/a/358145/50211)) seem to suggest that I can convert my OEM Windows XP, but for this I'd need to have an existing VLK installation CD to apply to the VM image, and I though (this being nearly 2012) I cannot purchase no Windows XP anymore.